# How do I write an if statement that checks for duplicate database entries?

Tags: php

How do I write an `if` statement in PHP that checks a database for `$varialbe` and have it only perform the action if `$varialbe` is not already in the database?

Comment: Depends on the action. If the action is inserting into a table, then there are ways you can go involving just the database which might be more efficient and maintainable, as well as just making the whole thing make more sense.  Of course, if you action is just about anything else (maybe the db table is a list of banned words?) then doing a simle `SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE column = '{$var}'` query and checking for **any** result is the best. I had an example, but I removed if because it was MySQL specific, and the question isn't; That said, check out PDO: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

You can count number of items in database by `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE field=?` query, and then insert record if there is no such records.

You can also [add `UNIQUE` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) to the table column you want to have only unique values

Answer (score 1):

```
if (! DBA::RowExists("select 1 from table where key = '$varialbe'"))
{
 ...
}
```